# Android Studio uses wrong different SDK version for different classes

Tags: android, android-studio

I faced a problem when Android Studio started marking code in red:
[image]

When I click to view source of findViewById() it takes me to sources of Android SDK 16 which is different from my project's compile SDK version (29).
At the same time in some other classes within the same project there is no such problem and findViewById works well. Clicking on it brings me to Android SDK 29 sources which is correct.
[image]

My project has compile SDK version set to 29, it's dependencies use compile sdk from 16 to 25.

I already tried:

1. Clean project.
2. Rebuild project.
3. Invalidate Caches / Restart
4. Reinstalling Android Studio and installing Beta version.
5. Tried to use different GIT commits where no such problem existed.
6. Deleted /.idea and /.gradle folders.
7. When I delete sources of Android SDK from ~/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-16 it helps until next rebuild (then Studio automatically downloads it again)

What started the problem: to fix GIT history I removed all files from working directory and copy-pasted a new version there. Not an elegant solution, I know, but there were no problems in git difference. The thing is that this "red code" problem now exists in all previous commits.

Project compiles without errors and application can be installed!

Please help!

**Update: this problem arrises only in Fragments! Somehow getView() in Fragment give me a different version of view?**

[image]

Comment: Are both source files in the same module? Also check all the .gradle files for potential issues. This does seem like a bug in Android Studio at first glance.

Comment: @JensV both files are in the same module. Please see my update.

Comment: This is indeed strange... If you got the time, I'd try deleting all your .AndroidStudio folders from your user directory, delete the .idea and .gradle files, delete the whole android sdk and try reimporting the project again. It does seem to be a IDE related issue if it compiles just fine

Comment: Deleted Android Studio and it's cache files. Didn`t help.

Comment: I don't know if we can help you besides uploading a sample project somewhere for us to test

Answer (score 0):

Solution found: 
update implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' to version 1.1.0. Don't now why this dependency started creating problems.